# how do I ignore a term in a route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a route that should have an optional/ignored last term.

Like so:

`/product/12345/Dark-Knight-Rises  # last term is just there for a nice URL`

I was thinking, from reading the docs, that I'd just be able to wildcard the last term:

`match 'product/:uid/*full_name' => 'product#view', :via => [:get]`

That didn't work. I did get this to work:

```
match 'product/:uid/:full_name'   => 'product#view', :via => [:get]
match 'product/:uid'              => 'product#view', :via => [:get]
```

But, well, it seems like this should be doable **in one line.** Yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match 'product/:uid(/:full_name)' => 'product#view', :via => [:get]` is what you are looking for

The parenthesis make the full_name an optional parameter which you can just ignore since all you want is a pretty URL.

Comment: Ah I see now, I needed to look for 'optional' instead of 'ignore': http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Below single line should work

```
match 'product/:uid/:full_name'   => 'product#view', :via => [:get]
```

Comment: That will still look for a url with a full name. You are missing the parenthesis around the full_name

Comment: @LeoCorrea Sorry I misunderstood the question.